# How to pass Backbone event handler function as string?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a Backbone view (SearchView) which have several search handlers. The search handler function must be dynamically passed as a string based on some process type.

Here is my code

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: wrapper,        
    process : "defaultHandler", 
    event: {},              
    template: _.template("<div id='cpntainer'><input type='button' id='search' value='Click Here'/><div>"),     
    initialize: function(options){
        this.render();          
        this.vent = options.vent;   
        this.options = options.process
        this.event = this.getEvent();           
    },                      
    getEvent : function(){          
        return {"click #search": this.process};
    },              
    searchHandler1: function( event ){
        alert('calling Handler1');              
    },
    searchHandler2: function( event ){
        alert('calling Handler1');              
    },
    searchHandler3: function( event ){
        alert('calling Handler1');              
    },
    defaultHandler: function( event ){
        alert('calling Deafault Handler');              
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());         
        return this;
    }       
}); 
var mainEvent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
var myView = new SearchView({ vent: mainEvent, process: "searchHandler1" });
```

**The problem is, event is not firing**, So what is wrong in this code??

Comment: Well, your problem is that you haven't created any event handlers - just a list of functions. Where did you think you were binding those functions to events?

Comment: this.event = this.getEvent();  added here  @Morslamina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly [define your events hash as a function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> The events property may also be defined as a function that returns an
>   events hash, to make it easier to programmatically define your events,
>   as well as inherit them from parent views.

For example,

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    process : "defaultHandler",
    events: function () {
        return {"click #search": this.process};
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.process = options.process;
    },                      

    searchHandler1: function (event) {
        console.log('calling Handler1');              
    },
    searchHandler2: function (event) {
        console.log('calling Handler2');              
    }   
});
```

and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/rzm21q0g/

Answer (score 1):

Your event object is called `event` - it should be `events`. See if that helps.

As to your second question (comment below) you're setting `this.options = options.process` it should be `this.process = options.process`.

Comment: Thanks @Morslamina it is typo mistake. Its a great help, but instead of calling searchHandler1 its calling defaultHandler. var myView = new SearchView({ vent: mainEvent, process: "searchHandler1" }); I am passing process as SearchHandler1

Comment: It's worth noting that @nikoshr had a good answer as well, and that is is probably best practice to do it that way - typos aside.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with having a single event handler with switch block on the processName? Try this:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: wrapper,        
    process : "defaultHandler", 
    events: {
        'click #search': 'onSearchClick'
    },              
    template: _.template("<div id='cpntainer'><input type='button' id='search' value='Click Here'/><div>"),     
    initialize: function(options){
        this.render();          
        this.vent = options.vent;   
        this.process = options.process        
    }, 
    onSearchClick: function(event){
        switch(this.process){
            case 'searchHandler1':
                alert('calling Handler1');
            break;
            case 'searchHandler2':
                alert('calling Handler2');
            break;
            case 'searchHandler3':
                alert('calling Handler3');
            break;
            default:
                alert('calling Deafault Handler');
            break;
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());         
        return this;
    }       
}); 
var mainEvent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
var myView = new SearchView({ vent: mainEvent, process: "searchHandler1" });
```